# DKIMPROXY signing wrong domain

Tags: postfix, smtp, email, dkim

Just.... wont sign a thing...

The dkimproxy_out.conf:

```
# specify what address/port DKIMproxy should listen on
listen    127.0.0.1:10028

# specify what address/port DKIMproxy forwards mail to
relay     127.0.0.1:10029

# specify what domains DKIMproxy can sign for (comma-separated, no spaces)
domain    tinymagnet.com,hypnoenterprises.com

# specify what signatures to add
signature dkim(c=relaxed)
signature domainkeys(c=nofws)

# specify location of the private key
keyfile   /etc/postfix/dkim/private.key

# specify the selector (i.e. the name of the key record put in DNS)
selector  mail
```

The direct connection straight to the server, making it clear that this is a problem with dkimproxy and not postfix...

```
mmxbass@hypno1:~$ telnet localhost 10028
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to localhost.localdomain.
Escape character is '^]'.
220 hypno1.hypnoenterprises.com ESMTP Postfix (Debian/GNU)
EHLO hypno1.hypnoenterprises.com
250-hypno1.hypnoenterprises.com
250-PIPELINING
250-SIZE
250-ETRN
250-STARTTLS
250-AUTH PLAIN LOGIN
250-AUTH=PLAIN LOGIN
250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
250-8BITMIME
250 DSN
MAIL FROM:<north@tinymagnet.com>
250 2.1.0 Ok
RCPT TO:<gln6su-dktest@test.myiptest.com>
250 2.1.5 Ok
DATA
354 End data with <CR><LF>.<CR><LF>
SUBJECT:test

.
250 2.0.0 Ok: queued as B62A78D94F
QUIT
221 2.0.0 Bye
```

Now lets look at the mail headers as reported by myiptest.com:

```
From north@tinymagnet.com Thu Dec 23 18:57:14 2010
Return-path: 
Envelope-to: jr9fpr-dktest@test.myiptest.com
Delivery-date: Thu, 23 Dec 2010 18:57:14 +0000
Received: from [184.82.95.154] (helo=hypno1.hypnoenterprises.com)
by myiptest.com with esmtp (Exim 4.69)
(envelope-from )
id 1PVqLi-0004YR-5f
for jr9fpr-dktest@test.myiptest.com; Thu, 23 Dec 2010 18:57:14 +0000
Received: from hypno1.hypnoenterprises.com (localhost.localdomain [127.0.0.1])
by hypno1.hypnoenterprises.com (Postfix) with ESMTP id 878418D902
for ; Thu, 23 Dec 2010 13:57:26 -0500 (EST)
DKIM-Signature: v=1; a=rsa-sha1; c=simple; d=hypnoenterprises.com; h=
from:to:subject:date:mime-version:content-type
:content-transfer-encoding:message-id; s=mail; bh=uoq1oCgLlTqpdD
X/iUbLy7J1Wic=; b=HxBKTGjzTpZSZU8xkICtARCKxqriqZK+qHkY1U8qQlOw+S
S1wlZxzTeDGIOgeiTviGDpcKWkLLTMlUvx8dY4FuT8K1/raO9nMC7xjG2uLayPX0
zLzm4Srs44jlfRQIjrQd9tNnp35Wkry6dHPv1u21WUvnDWaKARzGGHRLfAzW4=
Received: from localhost (localhost.localdomain [127.0.0.1])
by hypno1.hypnoenterprises.com (Postfix) with ESMTP id 2A04A8D945
for ; Thu, 23 Dec 2010 13:57:26 -0500 (EST)
X-Virus-Scanned: Debian amavisd-new at hypno1.hypnoenterprises.com
Received: from hypno1.hypnoenterprises.com ([127.0.0.1])
by localhost (hypno1.hypnoenterprises.com [127.0.0.1]) (amavisd-new, port 10024)
with ESMTP id Ua7BnnzmIaUO for ;
Thu, 23 Dec 2010 13:57:25 -0500 (EST)
Received: from phoenix.localnet (c-76-23-245-211.hsd1.ma.comcast.net [76.23.245.211])
(using TLSv1 with cipher DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA (256/256 bits))
(No client certificate requested)
by hypno1.hypnoenterprises.com (Postfix) with ESMTPSA id 48A0D8D90D
for ; Thu, 23 Dec 2010 13:57:25 -0500 (EST)
From: Joshua Pech 
To: jr9fpr-dktest@test.myiptest.com
Subject: test
Date: Thu, 23 Dec 2010 13:57:25 -0500
User-Agent: KMail/1.13.5 (Linux/2.6.32-5-amd64; KDE/4.4.5; x86_64; ; )
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: Text/Plain;
charset="us-ascii"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
Message-Id: 
DomainKey-Status: no signature
Received-SPF: pass (myiptest.com: domain of tinymagnet.com designates 184.82.95.154 as permitted sender)
```

Notice how the dkim signature specifies the d=hypnoenterprises.com.... why?

Answer (score 1):

Are you using a Sender Map File?

http://dkimproxy.sourceforge.net/manual/dkimproxy.out.html#sender_map_file

Looks like some init script hacking is necessary as the sample init script provided by DKIMProxy doesn't pass --sender_map

Look at this init script (not mine): http://www.pastie.org/579385/wrap

Report back, I'm going to have to do this shortly myself but haven't needed to yet.

Are you using multiple postfix instances?

Cheers